# CoreBlueTooth: what is the Service UUID FFE0 shorten for?

Tags: ios, bluetooth, uuid, core-bluetooth

I am doing a project to connect **iOS** with a devices equipped with **Bluetooth 4.0**.

The devices is bought from third party. (My iPhone as the central role) After connected to it, I print its **UUID**.

```
 for (CBService *service in peripheral.services) {

        NSLog(@"service :%@", service);
        NSLog(@"service uuid %@", service.UUID);

        [peripheral discoverCharacteristics:nil forService:service];
    }
```

The output is

```
2015-01-13 10:09:03.474 TestBTCC[3149:828116] service :<CBService: 0x17406f000, isPrimary = YES, UUID = FFE0>
2015-01-13 10:09:03.474 TestBTCC[3149:828116] service uuid FFE0
```

The **UUID** shall be 128bit. And 16bit should be a shorten format of some pre-defined **UUID**. What is it ?

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks/PerformingCommonPeripheralRoleTasks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257-CH4-SW8, I can use pre-defined shorten 16bit to generate **CBUUID**, like

```
 CBUUID *heartRateServiceUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString: @"180D"];
```

Can I directly write :

```
 CBUUID *heartRateServiceUUID = [CBUUID UUIDWithString: @"FFE0"];
```

regardless what it means ?

Answer (score 3):

FFE0 is a temperature characteristic, you won't have write permissions on this characteristic and the temperature will be read out in Celsius. You can either read the characteristic or subscribe to updates on it.

More information can be found [here](http://support.connectblue.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23035914).

Comment: Thanks anyway. I read the website you offered. It says **FFE1** (Temperature) is the only characteristic, and its type is **int8**. But actually, the devices here is not used for monitoring temperature. It has to send more data each time.

Comment: By the way, My devices is bought from a small-scale factory. It doesn't identified for **temperature used**. Can it send more data each time ?

Comment: The Bluetooth SIG defines the shortened characteristics to be standard so it _should_ be temperature. Are you scanning all centrals and all services or just the central and service UUID for the hardware you purchased?

Comment: My iPhone is as the central and I scan for the device providing the service. Now the question is : Even if the service is for **temperature**, can I use it for regular data transfer (sending or receiving any data I want )?

Comment: It will depend on the permissions of the peripheral. You'll need to read the [characteristic properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCharacteristic_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CBCharacteristicProperties) on the CBCharacteristic of the service to determine read and write permissions.

Comment: If the permissions of the peripheral are **read** and **write** supported. According to http://support.connectblue.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23035914, the **FFE1**'s data type is **int8**, it is possible to write longer bytes each time to **characteristic** ?

Comment: now I print the **characteristic**,`characteristic detail : <CBCharacteristic: 0x170085fa0, UUID = FFE1, properties = 0x16, value = (null), notifying = NO>`. **0X16** has no corresponding properties in https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCharacteristic_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/CBCharacteristicProperties